# wvdial, pppd and default route metric

Tags: gentoo, metric, pppd

I have this in wvdial.conf:

```
[Dialer Defaults]
Init1 = ATZ
Init2 = ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0
Modem Type = USB Modem
Phone = *99#
New PPD = yes
ISDN = 0
Username = foo
Init1 = ATZ
Password = foo
Modem = /dev/ttyUSB1
Baud = 9600
Stupid Mode = 0
#Init2 = ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0
Init3 = AT+CFUN=1
Init4 = AT+CGDCONT=1,"ip","internet"
Auto Reconnect = on
```

(PIN disabled)
This is working for 4G USB Dongle Huawei E3131 @ T-mobile.pl.

And now I have 2 questions:

## 1 How to translate this config to /etc/conf.d/net for connect as net.ppp1 (Gentoo) (I would connecting without wvdial)

## 2 After connecting I get default route with metric 0, How to change metric to say 100? (I'm interested in setting metric for both wvdial & pppd way)